# Can i use data binding in fx tag?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flex4, mxml

My application uses fx tag in which it loads some xml. I want to create the xml name by binding, but I get an error that **Data binding expressions not supported with attributes processed at compile time.**

```
<fx:XML id="{xml_props}"  />

<fx:XML id="{xml_props}"  />
```

Is there anyway to achive the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [the following documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mxml/xml.html). `fx:XML` tags is not loading XML file at runtime but embed it in compile time. If you need to load XML at runtime refer to [the following documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e6a.html).